# Anko dialog button title

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

With Anko, I can write something like this for showing dialog:

```
alert("Dialog title") {
   yesButton {}
   noButton {}
}.show()
```

How can I set a title for the button?

```
noButton {title = "title"}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`positiveButton`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/v.0.10.6/anko/library/static/appcompatV7/src/main/java/SupportAlertBuilder.kt#L80) and [`negativeButton`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/v.0.10.6/anko/library/static/appcompatV7/src/main/java/SupportAlertBuilder.kt#L88) like so:

```
alert("Dialog title") {
    positiveButton("Yes") { it.dismiss() }
    negativeButton("No") { it.dismiss() }
}.show()
```